# Let $f:[-2,5] \to \mathbb{R}$ integrable such as $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in [-2,5]$, therefore $\frac{1}{f}$ is integrable in $[-2,5]$. T/F?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f:[-2,5] \to \mathbb{R}$ integrable such as $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in [-2,5]$, therefore $\frac{1}{f}$ is integrable in $[-2,5]$.

I think that is true. Let's go for it.

Let $g:I \to \mathbb{R}$ where $ I=f([-2,5]) $ and $g$ is defined as $g(y)= \frac{1}{y}$.

That implies $g(y) = g(f(x)) $ where $f(x)$ is never 0.

We cannot be sure if $f$ is continuous. Since non continuous functions can be Riemann integrable (if the number of discontinuous points are enumerable). There is no way to know that (we don't have enough information) therefore we can just let this idea behind).

There is a theorem that states:

*If $0 < k < |f(x)|$ for all $x \in [a,b]$* then the quotient $g/f$ is integrable*

Since by definition we have $f(x) \neq 0$ and since $f$ domain is compact, the image is compact. Now we got the limited.

$f(x)$ satisfies the theorem therefore the quotient is integrable.

Is that correct?

Comment: Damn.. just continuous functions maps compacts to compacts.. I can't say anything..

Comment: And thus, you may spend some time thinking about possible counterexamples.

Comment: @DanielFischer that is false? that is a way to go...

Comment: $f(x)=x$ almost works ...

Comment: Yes I was thinking about $g(y)=1/y$ around $0$ the upper sum goes to $+\infty$ from right and the lower sum goes to $-\infty$ from the left side, since in the $V_\epsilon(0)$ the bounded sums do not converge implies that $g(0)$ isn't integrable. Makes sense?

Comment: More simply, Riemann integrable functions are bounded. (or, were you considering improper integrals?)

Comment: No .. not in this case. 

Thank you for the help.. That is the problem with analysis.. sometimes you hit the head against the wall.. and you don't notice it..

Thank you too @DanielFischer put me on right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is already in the comments, but to spell it out, take $f(x)=x$ for $x\ne 0$ and $f(0)=1$.